# Get max Id from my XML file?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jaxb

I used JAXB to generate my `XML` and used `XPATH` for get max id from my xml, but I have problem when I get max Id from my XML. Exception:"The provided JAXBContext [`class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl`] is not an EclipseLink JAXBContext, and therefore could not be converted."

this method for get max Id:

```
    public int  GetMaxID() throws JAXBException {
      try { 
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Project.class);
        XMLContext xmlContext = JAXBHelper.unwrap(jc, XMLContext.class);///**here is Exception**
        Project project = new Project();
        int maxId =xmlContext.getValueByXPath(project,"Project[not(Project/Layer/@idLayer>@idLayer)]",            null, int.class);
           }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
           }
         return -1;
     }
```

My xml :

```
<Project  name="p1"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <Layer idLayer="0">
    <LayerName>LayerName</LayerName>
  </Layer>
  <Layer idLayer="1">
    <LayerName>LayerName</LayerName>
  </Layer>
  <Layer idLayer="2">
    <LayerName>LayerName</LayerName>
  </Layer>
  <Layer idLayer="3">//**I want get this Id**
    <LayerName>LayerName</LayerName>
  </Layer>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAXB will create a Project class based on your XML

Your JAXB method is a little off... Also your Project class must match the XML content

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Project.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Project xmlData = (Project) unmarshaller.unmarshall(---XML CONTENT---);
```

then you do

```
xmlData.getLayer().get(xmlData.size()-1).getId();
```

take a look at this link http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

*edit you probably get the error you do because `Project` does not match your XML (ie doesn't have `Layer` or `LayerName` property

Comment: Thanks for answer, but you are not use Xpath in your code, please can you tell me how I can use xpath in my code for get max id.

Comment: its either JAXB or Xpath i dont see why you would use both. maybe you should do some research on Xpath http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/